# Matrix[i][j] index out of range for the 2D Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, tuples

**1. Given A of size 4 × 3 and K = 1 with bird habitats at (0, 0), (2, 2) and (3, 1)
the function should return 3. Wind turbines can be built in three locations: (0, 2), (1, 1) and (2, 0).**
In my code i have got an error of index out of range what should i can do to get my desired output.in the given case out put should be 3.

```
def solution(Matrix, K):
 row=len(Matrix)
 col=len(Matrix[0])
 K = K +1
 
 for i in (row):
   for j in (col):
    if Matrix[i][j] == 1:
       print(Matrix)
       fun(Matrix,i,j, K),

 res = 0,
 for i in (row):
   for j in (col):
    if Matrix[i][j] == 0:
      res += 1,
    return res,
 

def fun(Matrix,i,j,k):
  if k == 1:
   if i-1 >= 0:
      if Matrix[i-1][j]==0 or Matrix[i-1][j] >=2 and Matrix[i-1][j] <= k-1:
       Matrix[i-1][j]=k,
       fun(Matrix,i-1,j,k-1),
   if i+1 < len(Matrix):
      if Matrix[i+1][j] == 0  or Matrix[i+1][j] >=2 and Matrix[i+1][j] <= k-1:
       Matrix[i+1][j]=k,
       fun(Matrix,i+1,j,k-1)
   if j-1 >= 0:
     if Matrix[i][j-1]== 0 or Matrix[i][j+1] >= 2 and Matrix[i][j-1] <= k-1:
      Matrix[i][j-1]=k,
      fun(Matrix,i,j-1,k-1)
   if j+1 < len(Matrix[0]):
     if Matrix[i][j+1]== 0 or Matrix[i][j-1] >=2  and Matrix[i][j+1] <= k-1:
      Matrix[i][j+1]=k,
      fun(Matrix,i,j+1,k-1),
  return
```

Comment: Post code and error as text, not as screenshot. Explain **clearly** for that input you expect what output and why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. Given A of size 4 × 3 and K = 1 with bird habitats at (0, 0), (2, 2) and (3, 1):
A[0][0] = 1   A[0][1] = 0   A[0][2] = 0
A[1][0] = 0   A[1][1] = 0   A[1][2] = 0
A[2][0] = 0   A[2][1] = 0   A[2][2] = 1
A[3][0] = 0   A[3][1] = 1   A[3][2] = 0

the function should return 3. Wind turbines can be built in three locations: (0, 2), (1, 1) and (2, 0).

Answer (score 1):

In Solution with the code you are making tuples for row and col...

```
 row=len(Matrix),
 col=len(Matrix[0]),
 K = K +1;
```

Change your Code to actually save only the length as an int in your variable

```
row=len(Matrix)
col=len(Matrix[0])
K = K +1
```

Next Let's focus on this Part of your Mistake... This only works because it seems you don´t know how to create Variables and so it can loop through a tuple of what should be an int.

```
for i in (row):
   for j in (col):
    if Matrix[i][j] == 1:
       print(Matrix)
       fun(Matrix,i,j, K)
```

for i in number doesnt loop 0-number.... The way you defined your variables row would be a tuple with length 1 containing the length of the rows...
col would be a tuple with length 1 containing the length of cols...
eg:

col = {tuple: 1}
0 = {int} 6

```
for j in col: # would loop once with value 6
```

This results an error as your row and col are the length of an array. So you are basically trying to access an array with the index of its length.

eg. for a array index 0- 5 (length 6)
you are trying array[6]

Your proper Solution and the way the Program seems intended would be to loop the length of col and row (using range)
Lets take for example: row = 5, col = 6

```
for i in range(row):  # will loop through with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
   for j in range(col):  # will loop through with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    if Matrix[i][j] == 1:
       print(Matrix)
       fun(Matrix,i,j, K)
```

Comment: i do it in the same way as you mentioned it shows an other type of error TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got tuple..

Comment: CHange the way you define row and col

Comment: I gave you the answer how to solve your Error. Stack overflow is not here for people to do you work for you if you can't manage

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved out for the 2D matrix

```
    res = 0,
for i in range(len(Matrix)):
    for j in range(len(Matrix[0])):
      if Matrix[i][j] == 1:
      fun(Matrix,i,j, K),
   
for i in range(len(Matrix)):   
    for j in range(len(Matrix[0])):
    if Matrix[i][j] == 0:
    res=res[0]+1,
----------
```